# Understanding barycentric subdivision

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'd like to understand the inductive formula defining barycentric subdivision but I don't how $\mathcal{B}_0(\iota_1)$ is defined.

I'm referring to the following definition of barycentric subdivision ([Tom Dieck](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/diecktop.pdf) p.231)

[image]

I'd like to understand the formula given. In particular the first relevant case is $p=1$.

$$\mathcal{B}_1(\iota_1) = \iota_1^\beta \cdot \mathcal{B}_0(\partial\iota_1)$$

Why and how is $\mathcal{B}_0(\partial\iota_1)$ well-defined? And why this formula should give the geometric idea of continuously dividing simplexes adding the barycenter?

Any help or reference would be appreciated.

Comment: You've written $\mathcal B_0(\iota_1)$ where formula (2) has $\mathcal B_0(\partial\iota_1)$.  The latter is defined, as $\partial\iota_1$ is zero-dimensional.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thanks for the typo I edited it, yes but does not seem explicit, how could I compute it?

Comment: $\partial\iota_1$ is the difference of two singular $0$-simplices.  $\mathcal B_0$ is defined as a homomorphism, so it respects subtraction, and you have (in the passage you quoted) the definition of how $\mathcal B_0$ acts on $0$-simplices.